# spring-cloud-gateway RewritePath GatewayFilter not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am developing an spring-cloud-gateway application. Where I am using a RewritePath GatewayFilter for processing some `pathvariable`. Following is my downstream api running on **port 80**.

```
@GetMapping("/appname/event/{eventId}")
public Mono<ResponseEntity> getEventTimeOutWithPathVariable(
        @RequestHeader(name = "customerId") UUID customerId,
        @PathVariable(name = "eventId") String eventId) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("customerId", customerId);
    map.put("eventId", eventId);
    return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity(map, HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

And in My gateway application the filter configs are given as:

```
- id: api_timeout_route
  uri: http://localhost/appname/event/
  predicates:
  - Path=/withapitimeout/**
  filters:
  - Hystrix=apiTimeOut 
  - RewritePath=/withapitimeout/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

But it is not working . what I am doing wrong? I am getting the following log.

```
Mapping [Exchange: GET http://localhost:8000/withapitimeout/306ac5d0-b6d8-4f78-bde8-c470478ed1b1] 
to Route{id='api_timeout_route', uri=http://localhost:80/appname/event/
```

Mainly the path variable is not getting re-written. any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert but you can try something like this:

```
- id: api_timeout_route
  uri: http://localhost
  predicates:
  - Path=/withapitimeout/**
  filters:
  - Hystrix=apiTimeOut 
  - RewritePath=/withapitimeout/(?<segment>.*), /appname/event/$\{segment}
```

Let me know ;)